# Connecting points with lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have a CSV file with 2 columns with coordinates for the A side and 2 columns for the B side.
I have several identifiers in other columns if needed.

I want to connect these with a line between A and B side. Approx 5500 rows.

Column AE identifier
BC & BD used for A side
BE & BF used for B side

[image]

Data example:

```
Longitude Latitude  Expr1_Longitud Expr_1_Latitude 
1295791.166 6469378.367 1292369 6474768 
1295791.166 6469378.367 1296158 6470702
```

Comment: Just make sure points which belong to each other have the same ID, then load everything into QGIS and use `points to path/line`. Also, a data-example could be helpful.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than dumping lines of numbers in the comments which become hard to read. As to how QGIS can connect these points: Add a column which gives each row an ID, then load two points layers, one using the first two coordinates, one using the second pair of coordinates. Join these layers, then use `points to lines`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good place to use a geometry generator as the render.

Simply add in the file as using one set of coordinates as a delimited text layer.

Then open up the layer properties and in the symbology.

Choose, Geometry Generator form the Symbol layer type and using the expression:

```
make_line( make_point("Longitude", "Latitude"),   make_point("Expr1_Longitud", "Expr_1_Latitude"))
```

Like so:

[image]

Comment: If i want to save the layer as a kml with the lines how do i do that?

Comment: See answer by @JGH

Answer (score 3):

If you need the line for analysis (and not just for display), you can use a virtual layer.

The expression is very similar to the one provided by @HeikkiVesanto

go the menu `layer / add layer / add - edit virtual layer` then insert the query

```sql
SELECT referenceID, ST_make_line( ST_make_point("Longitude", "Latitude"), ST_make_point("Expr1_Longitud", "Expr_1_Latitude")) as geometry
```